# Resource files but not on culture code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

With resource files you can easily change text in views to show a localized languages. But as far as I can tell, it always works on an existing culture (EG: `nl-NL` or `en-US` or just `fr`).

Our application however does not need a different resource file based on culture, but on organization. Is it possible to define resource files like 'resource.company1.xml', 'resource.company2.xml'?

Option 2: These organisations access the same code via a seperate website/application pools, so they all have their own private static classes. Would it be a good approach to load all strings in a static class on application start and then access them from there? Once they are set, they dont change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to define resource files like 'resource.company1.xml', 'resource.company2.xml'?

No, resources work with Cultures.

> Option 2: These organisations access the same code via a seperate
>   website/application pools, so they all have their own private static
>   classes. Would it be a good approach to load all strings in a static
>   class on application start and then access them from there?

Yes, this is one possible solution. At `Application_Start` you could load the values by parsing the corresponding XML files and store them as static properties that you could access later.

Comment: 'this is one possible solution'. Do you think there is a better one?

Comment: I have very little context about your application in order to be able to assess something better.